# Why not full data?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, web-scraping, pythonanywhere

I try to get all specific span tags in all 3 urls
but finally the csv file only shows the data of last url.

Python code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd

urls = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    if i == 1:
        url = "https://www.coinbase.com/price/s/listed"
        urls.append(url)

    else:
        url = "https://www.coinbase.com/price/s/listed" + f"?page={i}"
        urls.append(url)
print(urls)

for url in urls:
    wd = webdriver.Chrome()
    wd.get(url)

    time.sleep(30)
    resp =wd.page_source
    html = BeautifulSoup(resp,"lxml")
    tr = html.find_all("tr",class_="AssetTableRowDense__Row-sc-14h1499-1 lfkMjy")
    print(len(tr))
    names =[]
    for i in tr:
        name1 = i.find("span",class_="TextElement__Spacer-hxkcw5-0 cicsNy Header__StyledHeader-sc-1xiyexz-0 kwgTEs AssetTableRowDense__StyledHeader-sc-14h1499-14 AssetTableRowDense__StyledHeaderDark-sc-14h1499-17 cWTMKR").text
        name2 = i.find("span",class_="TextElement__Spacer-hxkcw5-0 cicsNy Header__StyledHeader-sc-1xiyexz-0 bjBkPh AssetTableRowDense__StyledHeader-sc-14h1499-14 AssetTableRowDense__StyledHeaderLight-sc-14h1499-15 AssetTableRowDense__TickerText-sc-14h1499-16 cdqGcC").text
        names.append([name1,name2])

ns=pd.DataFrame(names)
date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
path = "/Users/paul/jpn traffic/coinbase/coinbase"
ns.to_csv(path+date+date+'.csv',index=None)
```

the result of 2 print() function, it returns nothing wrong:

```
print(urls):['https://www.coinbase.com/price/s/listed', 'https://www.coinbase.com/price/s/listed?page=2', 'https://www.coinbase.com/price/s/listed?page=3']
```

print(len(tr))

```
26
30
16
```

So what's wrong with my code? Why not full data?

BTW, if I want to run my code on cloud service everyday at a given time, which works better for me, as a green hand python learner? I don't need to store huge  data on cloud, I just need python scripts sending emails to my box that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not data? Answer is data is generating from backdoor meaning the site is using `API` that's why data is not with the help of BeautifulSoup. You can easily get data using api_url and requests. To get api_url go to chrome devtools then network tab then  xhr tab and click header tab then you will get the url and click preview tab to see data.

Now, data is generating:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.coinbase.com/api/v2/assets/search?base=BDT&country=BD&filter=listed&include_prices=true&limit=30&order=asc&page=2&query=&resolution=day&sort=rank')
coinbase = r.json()['data']

for coin in coinbase:
    print(coin['name'])
```